# Different URLs for individual sheets within a single document

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to create several individual URLs (in other words, endpoints) for a particular sheet in a given document. I have data (not much, about 200-250 rows). Basically, data structure is exactly the same every year (ID, Country, Title, Name etc.). I have managed to transform selected cells into proper JSON format and deploy the following as a Web Application.

I'm currently using the `doGet()` method, which body can be found below.

I tried to use official Google Documentation, but it seems to me that I do not fully understand it.

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web#url_parameters

```js
function doGet(e) 
{
    var sheetName = "Lorem Ipsum";
    var sheetID = "SDJHFLKSDJFLJSD94UF940FUJ9FS90FJ049JW9F";
    var book = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sheetID);
    var sheet = book.getSheetByName(sheetName);
    var JSON = convertSheet2JsonText(sheet);
    return ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify(JSON)).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
}

[
    {
        "ID": 1,
        "PUBLISHED": true,
        "NAME": "Lorem Ipsum",
        "TITLE": "Lorem Ipsum",
        "SOURCE": "Lorem Ipsum",
        "DATE": "14 June 2019",
        "COUNTRY": "Poland"
    },
    {
        "ID": 2,
        "PUBLISHED": false,
        "NAME": "Lorem Ipsum",
        "TITLE": "Lorem Ipsum",
        "SOURCE": "Lorem Ipsum",
        "DATE": "05 August 2019",
        "COUNTRY": "USA"
    }
]
```

Basically, just after deploy, I get a link, but it contains data only from one sheet to which I provided the ID. The expected result should look like this:

- URL: ../macros/s/../exec/data-2018
- URL: ../macros/s/../exec/data-2019
- URL: ../macros/s/../exec/data-2020

Answer (score 0):

**Problem**

Unfortunately, WebApps deployed on Google infrastructure don't support routing per se, you get only one URL for each project ending with `/exec` for production and `/dev` for development environment respectively.

**Solution**

Fortunately, you can append a *query string* to this URL if you want to specify which function to run / ID to use, etc. Think of the `doGet()` / `doPost()` as the router in this case: `/exec?param1=value1&param2=value2`. Every parameter you pass to query string will be conveniently available from the *event object* under either `parameter` or `parameters` key.

**Sample**

If I understood you correctly, you want to route the WebApp by `sheetName` property, right? Then, your URL should look like `/exec?name=data-2018` (btw, don't forget to properly encode it, especially if your names contain whitespaces) and you should access this parameter in `doGet`:

```
function doGet(e) {
    var param     = e.parameter; //access query params;
    var sheetName = param.name;

    var sheetID = 'yourId';
    var book = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sheetID);
    var sheet = book.getSheetByName(sheetName);
    var JSON = convertSheet2JsonText(sheet);
    return ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify(JSON)).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
}
```

**Useful links**

1. Event object [structure](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web#request_parameters) (+one of my older [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56239726/11407695));
2. URL encoding [reference](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp);